# Complements of open sets are closed

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

In a metric space $(X,d)$, if $U \subseteq X$ is open, then its complement $U^c$ is closed.

Suppose $U$ is open. Then $\forall v \in U, \exists \varepsilon>0 \ni B_{\varepsilon}(v) \subseteq U$. To prove that $U^c$ is closed, we need only to show that $(a_n) \in U^c$ convergent $\Rightarrow (a_n) \to b$, where $b \in U^c$.

Let $(a_n) \in U^c$ be convergent whereby $(a_n) \to b$ for some $b \in X$. Choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $n>N$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then $d(a_n,b)<\varepsilon \in (0,\infty)$.

But if $(a_n) \in U^c$, doesn't that mean $a: \mathbb{N} \to X \setminus U$ since $U^c=X \setminus U$. So the only possible values it can take are in the codomain (i.e. $X \setminus U$). So if its convergent, then its limit should be in $X \setminus U$?

Any insight would be appreciated! Note that here closed sets are defined based on the limits of convergent sequences, and not in terms of limit points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question the answer is no. For example, the converging series $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$ lies entirely in $(0,1]$, but its limit doesn't.

Now, take $\{a_n\}_{n\in\Bbb{N}}\subset U^c$ s.t $a_n$ converges to $a$. We want to prove $a\in U^c$.
Now, we know that since $a_n$ converges to $a$, by definition for every open neighborhood $B_\varepsilon(a)$, there is atleast one element of $a_n$ (actually there are infinitely many but that's not important here). Assume for a contradiction that $a\in U$. $U$ is open and therefore there exists $\varepsilon>0$ s.t $B_\varepsilon(a)\subset U$. But, for every $n$, $a_n\not\in U$ and therefore for every $n$, $a_n\not\in B_\varepsilon(a)$, a contradiction to the fact that $a_n\rightarrow a$.

Comment: why do you say that since $a_n$ converges to $a$, then by definition of every open neighborhood $B_{\varepsilon}(a)=\{y \in X | d(a,y) < \varepsilon \}$, there $\exists$ at least one element $a(n) \in B_{\varepsilon}(a)=\{y \in X | d(a,y) < \varepsilon \}$? Is that because $(a_n)$ converges to $a \in X$, so once $n \ge N$ for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$, then we always have $d(a_n,a)<\varepsilon$ for every $n \ge N$?

Comment: @Karam Exactly. Every open neighborhood centered at $a$ is $B_\varepsilon(a)$ for some $\varepsilon$.